# Set and Check two bit flags

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

What I actually want to do:

Have 4 conditions. Maximum 2 will be set. There are maximal 4 valid combinations.

```
$types = array(
    "A" => 0x1,
    "B" => 0x2,
    "C" => 0x4,
    "D" => 0x8,
);
```

We can have A/B + C/D (=AC, AD, BC, BD)

```
$flags = $types["A"] | $types["C"];    
if ($flags & ($types['A'] | $types['D'])) 
    echo "true";
else
    echo "false";

// output: "true"
```

Okay I'm already fiddling around with this for .. well way too long.

How do I set and check two flags correctly?

```
// pseudo code explanation
x = A + D
if(x = A+C) do something
```

Comment: so basically `if ($flags & (A|B)) || ($flags & (C|D)) { .. invalid combo ... }`? e.g. if a&b are both set, then that's invalid, and same for c&d?

Comment: @MarcB Absolutely correct